# Can't use deployed TF BERT model to get GCloud online predictions from SavedModel: "Bad Request" error

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I trained a BERT model based on [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb).

I export it as a tf SavedModel this way:

```
def serving_input_fn():
    receiver_tensors = {
        "input_ids": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH])
    }

    features = {
        "input_ids": receiver_tensors['input_ids'],
        "input_mask": 1 - tf.cast(tf.equal(receiver_tensors['input_ids'], 0), dtype=tf.int32),
        "segment_ids": tf.zeros(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH]),
        "label_ids": tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='label_ids')
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)


estimator._export_to_tpu = False
estimator.export_saved_model("export", serving_input_fn)
```

Then if I try to use the saved model locally it works:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model("export/1575241274/")

print(predict_fn({
    "input_ids": [[101, 10468, 99304, 11496, 171, 112, 10176, 22873, 119, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
}))

# {'probabilities': array([[-0.01023898, -4.5866656 ]], dtype=float32), 'labels': 0}
```

Then I uploaded the SavedModel to a bucket and created a model and a model version on gcloud this way:

```
gcloud alpha ai-platform versions create v1gpu --model [...] --origin=[...] --python-version=3.5 --runtime-version=1.14 --accelerator=^:^count=1:type=nvidia-tesla-k80 --machine-type n1-highcpu-4
```

No issue there, the model is deployed and displayed as working in the console.

But if I try to get predictions, as such:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
name = 'projects/[project_name]/models/[model_name]/versions/v1gpu'

response = service.projects().predict(
        name=name,
        body={'instances': [{
    "input_ids": [[101, 10468, 99304, 11496, 171, 112, 10176, 22873, 119, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
}]}
).execute()

print(response["predictions"])
```

All I get is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[project_name]/models/[model_name]/versions/v1gpu:predict?alt=json returned "Bad Request">
```

I get the same error if I test the model from the gcloud console using the "Test your model with sample input data" feature.

**Edit:**

The saved_model has a tagset "serve" and signature_def "serving_default".

Output of "saved_model_cli show --dir 1575241274/ --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default":

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input_ids'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (1, 128)
      name: Placeholder:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['labels'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: ()
      name: loss/Squeeze:0
  outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 2)
      name: loss/LogSoftmax:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Answer (score 0):

The body of the request sent to the API has the form:

```
{"instances": [<instance 1>, <instance 2>, ...]}
```

As specified in documentation we need something like this:

```
{
    "instances": [
        <object>
        ...
    ]
}
```

In this case you have:

```
{ 
    "instances": [ 
        {
           "input_ids": 
             [ <object> ] 
        }

     ...
    ]
}
```

You need to replace input_ids to instances:

```
{  
    "instances": 
     [
        [101, 10468, 99304, 11496, 171, 112, 10176, 22873, 119, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
     ]
}
```

**Note** If you can show the `saved_model_cli` will be great.

Also `gcloud local predict` command is also a good option for testing.

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion did not work unfortunately (same error). I added an edit to my question with the output of saved_model_cli.

Comment: Hey @gogasca, it's been a while but could you by any chance take a look at the edit? I'm still stuck on this.

Comment: Are you still trying to sol e this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depend of the signature of the model. In my case I have the following signature (just keeping the input part):

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['attention_mask'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1, 128)
      name: serving_default_attention_mask:0
  inputs['input_ids'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1, 128)
      name: serving_default_input_ids:0
  inputs['token_type_ids'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1, 128)
      name: serving_default_token_type_ids:0
```

and I need to pass data in the following format (in this case 2 examples):

```
{'instances': 
  [
    {'input_ids': [101, 143, 18267, 15470, 90395, ...], 
     'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .....], 
     'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .....]
     }, 
     {'input_ids': [101, 17664, 143, 30728, .........], 
      'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .......], 
      'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....]
      }
  ]
}
```

I am using it with a `Keras` model with `Tensorflow` `2.2.0`

I guess in your case you need (for 2 examples):

```
{'instances': 
  [
    {'input_ids': [101, 143, 18267, 15470, 90395, ...]}, 
    {'input_ids': [101, 17664, 143, 30728, .........]}
  ]
}
```